# What is the differences between "data packet" and "transaction"?

Tags: database

What is the meaning of "packet" in database systems ? And its differences with transaction ?
If anyone can help me or introduce an ebook or article ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) are not specific to databases but to networked processes or applications in general. A data packet typically is part of a network protocol and can contain a certain number if bytes in a format specified by the protocol.

A [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is a logical grouping of operations so that they are either performed and observed completely or not at all.

So, data packets and transaction are really different animals. If one any wants see where these concepts might relate, I might try. I see the following connections:

- Packets might get lost, delayed, corrupted or duplicated. Ensuring
  transactions will require extra work under these conditions.
- Several packets might be needed to transfer the whole data of a
  transaction.
- A distributed transaction will have to coordinate the
  data packets between multiple processes.
- A packet in a higher level protocol might be implemented by several packets in the next lower protocol. This can be viewed like a transaction because many protocols ensure that a packet arrives wholly or not at all. This is perhaps the best relation between packet and transaction.

Comment: i answered to this question like you but my teacher said "no , what is the meaning of packets in DBMS architecture concepts ?"

Comment: I augmented the answer with a try of relating both concepts.